# Wrong URL for category image when root is set to pub directory

Tags: url, security, pub, webroot

I want to use `pub/` directory for security reasons as *document root* for Magento website but when i switch it, images for *categories* and for *manufacturers* (in product detail) are not displayed.

I follow [Modify docroot to improve security](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html) instructions from Magento documentation and products pictures are displayed well, but URLs for *categories* and *manufacturers* images are still generated with `pub/` prefix and so it ends with *404 Not found*

I use

- GNU/Linux Debian 10
- Apache 2.4
- MariaDB 10.3
- PHP 7.2
- Redis 5.0
- Magento 2.3

Does anyone have an idea what should I do to fix this? Thanks

Update: Few other findings

- Category images are show correctly in admin interface
- `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` does not help

Comment: Were you able to fix this? Encountering same thing.

Comment: Sadly, no. I ended up with document root set to original location.